# Calling JS from a flash video

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I need to create a really basic flash video (actionscript 2) where I click on a bit of text which will call a javascript function. I'm really new to actionscript so please forgive me if this is a trivial question...

I have created a flash video which has a bit of text I converted to a button symbol. I then opened the "Actions" tab and added:

```
on (press) {
    import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
    ExternalInterface.call("test");
    trace("Foo");
}
```

Which when I debug will print "Foo" to the output window. However when I put this flash video on a page with the following js in the header nothing happens...

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function test() {
        alert("Hey");
    }
</script>
```

I thought that it might be something to do with ExternalInterface.call so I tried getUrl("javascript:test()") which popped up a security warning (so the pressed event must be firing) but then did nothing when I ok'd the warning.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Is the function `test()` defined above the Flash object in your page?

Comment: hey yeah, i've also tried ExternalInterface.call("alert", "hey"); which should just call the inbuilt alert function but still nothing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scripts looks OK to me, maybe it could be that you need to set the [AllowScriptAccess](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/164/tn_16494.html) parameter in the HTML (or SwfObject JavaScript) that embeds the swf in the HTML page.

Comment: woo! turns out the html was outputting <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />. changing that to <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" /> worked a treat! thanks!